# Extracting a variable set of key/value in JSON using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON object that is dynamically generated and has a structure as shown below:

```js
[
  {id:"1", static1:"aa", var1:"1", var2:"2", var3:"3", static2:"hello"},
  {id:"2", static1:"bb", var1:"1", var2:"2", var3:"3", static2:"hello"},
  {id:"3", static1:"cc", var1:"1", var2:"2", var3:"3", static2:"hello"},
  {id:"4", static1:"dd", var1:"1", var2:"2", var3:"3", static2:"hello"},
  {id:"5", static1:"ee", var1:"1", var2:"2", var3:"3", static2:"hello"}
]
```

The static keys (e.g., "static1", "static2") will always be present. But there can be any number of variable keys (e.g., "var1", "var2", and so on). And these variable keys will always be preceded by the key "static1" and followed by "static2".

Having said that, what is the most performant way to extract all of the variable keys/values from the JSON object using jQuery? Only the core jQ library is to be used.

Comment: `And these variable keys will always be preceded by the key "static1" and followed by "static2"` - that's not true at all - keys in an object are unordered.

Comment: This isn't even valid JSON data

Comment: ...it sounds like you're saying there will be multiple keys with the same name (`var1`, `var2`), the only distinguishing characteristic being the `static` key that they follow - however tymeJV pointed out the main issue here, and furthermore, you can't have duplicate keys. It seems like you would be much better off with nested objects. Also, valid JSON assumes your keys are wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Do you simply want to iterate through all the properties of each object, and exclude properties called `id`, `static1` and `static2` (or anything of the pattern `/static\d+/`)?

Comment: @tymeJV - Just so I understand, are you saying the order in which I see these keys in the resultant JSON isn't necessary how they are actually ordered?

Comment: @BinaryCat That's correct -- Two JSON object with the same properties but different orders both convey completely identical semantics. Order of properties is not information that JSON intentionally conveys; [the JSON spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159) explicitly calls an object an "unordered collection".

Comment: @m_callens - Thanks for calling out the validity of the JSON. I manually typed in the JSON with made up key names and values, but as stated in the question, its structure follows closely of the resultant JSON I need to work with.

Comment: What is higher level goal with these variables?

Comment: @charlietfl - The variable keys/values are fed into another jQ plug-in that renders the data in an Excel-like grid.

Comment: In what format/structure? This sounds like columns/headings? Would be a lot easier if you control source of the data shown, and structure it more appropriately

Comment: @charlietfl - Yes, there will be columns and rows of data when it's all said and done. Sorry if it wasn't clear in my earlier response. Now it's looking more and more like a discussion I need to have with the one who's responsible for generating this JSON.

Comment: sure would be ... this would be very simple using consistent property names and nested arrays ... `{headings:['h1','h2'], values:[[1,2,5,6], [5,8,9,0]]}`

Answer (score 1):

if ID, static1 & static2 is fixed, variable data length will be object length - 3; and then loop through it.

```
var arr = [
   {id:"1", static1:"aa", var1:"1", var2:"2", var3:"3", static2:"hello"},
   {id:"2", static1:"bb", var1:"1", var2:"2", var3:"3", static2:"hello"},
   {id:"3", static1:"cc", var1:"1", var2:"2", var3:"3", static2:"hello"},
   {id:"4", static1:"dd", var1:"1", var2:"2", var3:"3", static2:"hello"},
   {id:"5", static1:"ee", var1:"1", var2:"2", var3:"3", static2:"hello"}
   ]

   var obj = {};
   var size = 0;
   var varLength = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     obj = arr[i];
     size = Object.keys(obj).length;
     varLength = size - 3;
     for(var j=1; j <= varLength; j++) {
       var varData = obj["var"+j];
       console.log(varData);
       //Do your work here
     }
   }
```

Plunker url https://plnkr.co/edit/h3xHNXq9IhVJpLGZ4N8H?p=info

Answer (score 0):

I would use reflection to iterate over the objects properties

```
for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if(property.search("static") > -1) {
               // extract the property
                var pieceOfData = object[property]; 
              // do what you gotta do
            }
        }
    }
```